# How to integrate BotBoot captcha and disable submit button until captcha is correct?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, captcha

I call upon the amazing JavaScript Guru Masters once again!
Please heed my call as I am failing again~

So I'm using BotBoot JavaScript Captca, it does the "Are you Human? 6 + 8 = ?" question. I would like the submit button to be disabled until the recaptca passes true.

So my botboot.js file looks like this:

```
var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);       
var c = a + b;
function DrawBotBoot()
{
    document.write("<label for='botboot' class='contact_label'>What is "+ a + " + " + b +"?</label>");
    document.write("<input name='botboot' id='BotBootInput' type='number' class='input_field' maxlength='2' size='2' required>");
}    
function ValidBotBoot(){
    var d = document.getElementById('BotBootInput').value;
    if (d == c) return true;        
    return false;  
}
```

My form is this:

```
<script src="js/botboot.js"></script>
<form action="send-mail.php" class="contact" method="post" parsley-validate>
    <label for="name" class="contact_label">Name</label>
    <br>
    <input name="name" type="text" class="input_field" required><br>

    <label for="email" class="contact_label">Email</label>
    <br>
    <input name="email" type="email" class="input_field" parsley-trigger="blur" parsley-focus="first" required><br>

    <label for="phone" class="contact_label">Phone</label>
    <br>
    <input name="phone" type="tel" class="input_field" parsley-trigger="change"><br>

    <label for="message" class="contact_label">Message</label>
    <br>
    <textarea name="message" class="input_field_message" parsley-trigger="keyup" parsley-rangelength="[20,200]" parsley-focus="last" required></textarea><br>

    <script>DrawBotBoot()</script><br>

    <submit class="btn btn-lg btn-default cta">Submit</submit>
</form>
```

Thank you for your time, skills, and brain power JavaScript Guru Masters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified a few parts of your code to get this working. A working JSFiddle can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/QVXS3/1/.

The first part of the code I modified was the HTML (mostly for JSFiddle Purposes).

```
<div id="botboot"></div>
<input type="submit" id="form_submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default cta" name="Submit" disabled>
<script>DrawBotBoot()</script><br>
```

This creates a container where the BotBoot will be placed and I changed the submit button to a normal input type so the `disabled` attribute will work.

The next part is the JavaScript.

```
function DrawBotBoot() {
    var div = document.getElementById('botboot');
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.name = 'botboot';
    input.id = 'BotBootInput';
    input.type = 'number';
    input.class = 'input_field';
    input.setAttribute('maxlength','2');
    input.setAttribute('size','2');
    input.setAttribute('required','required');
    input.addEventListener('keyup',ValidBotBoot,false);
    div.innerHTML += "<label for='botboot' class='contact_label'>What is "+ a + " + " + b +"?</label>";
    div.appendChild(input);
}    
function ValidBotBoot(e) {
    var submit = document.getElementById('form_submit');
    var d = e.target.value;
    if (d == c) {
        submit.removeAttribute('disabled');
        return true;   
    }else{
        submit.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    }
    return false;  
}
```

I manually created the input element using the function of `createElement`. This allows me to easily add an event listener to the item so we can detect when the user types anything in this field. I set the `innerHTML` of the `botboot` div to add the label. I then `appendChild` to include the input we created.

Inside of the `ValidBotBoot` I added the `e` parameter to catch the event details that is passed. The `d` variable is now that of the event's target value. We also have to get the submit button which I do so by getting the element by the id of `form_submit`. If the variable `d == c` I then remove the disabled attribute.

I know that this code is kinda sloppy, but hopefully you can polish it up to fit your needs a lot better and that this will atleast give you a starting point.

Comment: Sweet,I know i posted this a long time ago, but now I can use this for human validation over the ugly and annoying google recaptcha. Thanks!

Comment: I was shocked how old this question was. Today it randomly appeared on the front page for me.

Comment: _I am no JS master, but more like JS hack._ But I love this answer / solution. I have added some IE 7&8 handling for any other hacks outs there.  http://jsfiddle.net/g94f6/